# Looping through values obtained from Dataframe and creating a new variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that has latitude and longitude of a bunch of address as below

```
lat, long
25.234, -76.433
25.175, -74.843
```

Raw input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [25.234, 25.175], 'long': [-76.433, -74.843]})
```

I am trying to create a variable that stores values pulled from this Dataframe and creates value as below.

```
value = '(SQRT(POW(69.1 * (S.latitude - latitude_value), 2) + POW(69.1 * (longitude_value - S.longitude) * COS(S.latitude / 57.3), 2)) <= 0.2)'
```

How can I loop through each row and have this `value` variable have all the lat/ long created in the above format

Expected output:

```
value = '(SQRT(POW(69.1 * (S.latitude - 25.234), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-76.433 - S.longitude) * COS(S.latitude / 57.3), 2)) <= 0.2) OR 
         (SQRT(POW(69.1 * (S.latitude - 25.175), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-74.843 - S.longitude) * COS(S.latitude / 57.3), 2)) <= 0.2)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `'latitude_value'` and `'longitude_value'` in `value` with `{}` so that you can use `str.format` method in apply function to fill in the string's placeholder.

```
value = '(SQRT(POW(69.1 * (S.latitude - latitude_value), 2) + POW(69.1 * (longitude_value - S.longitude) * COS(S.latitude / 57.3), 2)) <= 0.2)'.replace('latitude_value', '{}').replace('longitude_value', '{}')

out = ' OR '.join(df.apply(lambda x: value.format(x['lat'], x['long']), axis=1).tolist())
```

Output:

```
'(SQRT(POW(69.1 * (S.latitude - 25.234), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-76.433 - S.longitude) * COS(S.latitude / 57.3), 2)) <= 0.2) OR (SQRT(POW(69.1 * (S.latitude - 25.175), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-74.843 - S.longitude) * COS(S.latitude / 57.3), 2)) <= 0.2)'
```